# I am a newbie in Programming in java and clearly not understanding the error i am getting in this project

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am not getting why is it giving me following error:

> //Error:(47, 36) java: 'void' type not allowed here//

whereas I am not returning anything in the constructor. Also kindly suggest me good books or some place to learn the concepts of Java. basic and OOP.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
   String name;


public void Main()
{
    this.name= "";
}

public void Main(String pname){
    this.name = pname;
    System.out.println("Hey"+name+"welcome to Washroom, what do you wish to listen??");
    System.out.println("Press, 1 for Elon Musk Audios \n" +
            "Press, 2 for calm Music \n" +
            "Press 3 for random songs");
}
public void MusicInitiation(int option)
{
    if(option == 1){
        ElonMusk();
    }
    else if(option== 2){
        CalmMusic();
    }
        else if(option == 3)
    {
        RandomSongs();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Hey you havent enetered the right option.");

    }
}


public void ElonMusk()
{

}
public void CalmMusic()
{

}
public void RandomSongs()
{

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main obj = new Main();

    System.out.println(obj.Main("Hafsa"));
```

Comment: It would help if you would highlight the line of the error.

Comment: Write your complete main function please and also highlight the line number *error* of your code.

Comment: Hello Hafsa Java Constructor don't have a return type,they can  not return any value.No need to have a void.

Comment: Constructors do not have return types (not even `void`). Use `public Main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two answers are correct; I'm going to try to be a bit more explicit.

You can't have a

```
public void Main() {}
```

in a class named Main. The reason is that a method with the same name as the class is a constructor. Constructors must no specify a return type, including void. It's the way Java is set up.

The fact that your Main() method starts with a capital letter is a hint. Unfortunately, most of your methods start with capitals. In Java standard practice, methods start with a lower-case letter, except for constructors.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.Main()` returns void.

```
public void Main(String pname)
```

You are trying to pass void to `System.out.println` which is expecting a String.

```
System.out.println(obj.Main("Hafsa"));
```

To fix this, just remove the `println`:

```
obj.Main("Hafsa")
```

---

Your "default constructor" is also declared incorrectly. You've declared a method.

```
public void Main() // a method with the same name of the class i.e. Main.Main()
```

should be

```
public Main()
```

---

Methods should be [lowerCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and you should try to choose more specific identifiers. Here's a refactored version:

```
class MusicApp
{
    private final String username;

    public MusicApp()
    {
        this.username = "";
    }

    public MusicApp(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void printWelcomeMessage()
    {
        System.out.println("Hey" + username + "welcome to Washroom, what do you wish to listen??");
        System.out.println("Press, 1 for Elon Musk Audios \n" +
                "Press, 2 for calm Music \n" +
                "Press 3 for random songs");
    }

    public void musicInitiation(int option)
    {
        if (option == 1) {
            elonMusk();
        } else if (option == 2) {
            calmMusic();
        } else if (option == 3) {
            randomSongs();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hey you havent enetered the right option.");
        }
    }

    private void elonMusk() {}
    private void calmMusic(){}
    private void randomSongs(){}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MusicApp musicApp = new MusicApp("Michael");
        musicApp.printWelcomeMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your's

```
public void Main()
{
    this.name= "";
}
public void Main(String pname){}
```

retype

```
public  Main()
{
    this.name= "";
}
public Main(String pname){}
```

So the reason the constructor doesn't return a value is because it's not called directly by your code, it's called by the memory allocation and object initialization code in the runtime----

[web site]Tutorial point,udacity,.. are great place for learn.